# Missing $ inserted \begin{pmatrix} error

Tags: matrices

I am getting the "Missing $ inserted \begin{pmatrix}" error in the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

 %opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{\sigma}_{11} & \dots & \tilde{\sigma}_{1d}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\tilde{\sigma}_{d1} & \dots & \tilde{\sigma}_{dd}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `pmatrix` environment *must* occur in math mode: either inline math mode or (more likely) display math mode.

The following code should compile just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\newcommand\tsigma{\tilde{\sigma}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\[ % enter display math mode
\begin{pmatrix}
\tsigma_{11} & \dots  & \tsigma_{1d}\\
\vdots       & \ddots & \vdots      \\
\tsigma_{d1} & \dots  & \tsigma_{dd}
\end{pmatrix}
\] % end display math mode
\end{document}
```